# Using RPi touchscreen in bash

Tags: python, bash, unix, raspberry-pi

I have an Raspberry Pi with *dietpi* rom flashed on SDcard and waveshare 3.5 display with touchscreen. I want to read touch signal from bash using python 3.9. Technically touchscreen is just a reimagination of mouse, but any module that i have used for reading mouse signal didn't work properly. For example python module *pynput* requires X server running, means i need a "desktop" to run scripts with *pynput* module.

---

Edit: python module *mouse* actually can read USB mouse input, but still touchscreen is unreachable for me.

Comment: Typically you have an X server to work with the mouse / touchscreen. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I am trying to use touchscreen from generic CLI of unix-systems. I have an dietpi os running in my RPi and it does not have a "windows" interface, just bash I/O terminal.  Moreover i don't want to use any desktops to run this script, so i basically need only to read, if user touched display, or not.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @U12-Forward There is no code. I actually have no idea how to do that.